# NullReferenceException was unhandled in TcpListener in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, tcp, tcplistener

I am trying to connect `TcpListener` to localhost for ip address 127.0.0.1 and port number 8081
but I'm getting an error

> NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

And here is my code ...

```
public class Listener
{
    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread listenThread;

    Int32 port = 8081;
    IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];

    public void ListenForClients()
    {
        //getting error at this line..
        this.tcpListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            //blocks until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //create a thread to handle communication 
            //with connected client
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }

    public void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                //blocks until a client sends a message
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                //a socket error has occured
                // System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("socket");
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server
                // System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("disc");
                break;
            }

            //message has successfully been received
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

            String textdata = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"D:\ipdata.txt", textdata);



            //mainwind.setText(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
            // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
        }

        tcpClient.Close();
    }
}
```

And I am getting error at the following line of the code...

```
this.tcpListener.Start();
```

Comment: You dont create a new instance of `tcpListener` anywhere.. try adding something like `tcpListener = new TcpListener (..)`

Answer (score 2):

Your TcpListener is null. You need to call new on it and create an actual instance of it.

```
private TcpListener tcpListener;
```

Should probably be

```
private TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener();
```

Comment: creating instance is giving error

Answer (score 2):

You have only declared `tcpListener`

```
private TcpListener tcpListener;
```

It is not having any value. It is null.

You have to define it first before using it.

try

```
private TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener();
```